# Website not updating content and files deployed on AWS

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dirpagination

I have an angularjs website Hosted at AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Earlier website had a HTML smart table grid. which we later replaced it with simple table with ng-repeat. For pagination dirpagination.js is used.
https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination 
Everything works fine locally. But when deployed on AWS environment content doesn't get updated . sometimes Network tab (browser) shows dirpagination cannot be found, while sometimes it loads.
Any help would be grateful.